# Moving Android View and preventing onDraw to be called over and over again

Tags: java, android, view

I'm extending the `View`-class, to what I call `MyView`. (I've added some properties which basically says what is drawn on the object, and handling this)

I'm moving an object of this class once every few milliseconds, this works great. I'm using `this.layout(left, top, right, bottom);` to move the MyView. But it seems like every time the view is moved, it is redrawn (onDraw is called). Is this necessary? The contents of `MyView` does not change when it is moved. In fact, the contents will never change - it's created in one way, moves around, and later gets destroyed.

I'm using `onDraw` because every time it is created I want it to draw some text or some numbers on it. I used to extend `ImageView` and use `setImageResource` but I realized I want more than just different images on this and creating images for all kinds of text and number content this object can have did not feel right.

It is also important that my object can receive onTouch events, which works fine today.

My onDraw-method contains at the moment: (this will change, when I get it to not repaint all the time)

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setARGB(255, 0, 255, 255);
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 32, 32, p);
}
```

So the question is: Can I have an object that is **drawn dynamically when created**, have the possibility to **receive touch events** (I could solve this another way so it's not very important), and **move it around without it being repainted (most important)?**

The reason is: I'm going to have several objects (could be 100+) of this class and I believe that the application will be slowed down by repainting the objects all the time.

Edit:
If it's not possible with a View, is there **any alternative that I can use?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But it seems like every time the view is moved, it is redrawn (onDraw is called). Is this necessary?

**Yes.**

A `View` object will ALWAYS call `onDraw` whenever its moved since invalidate method must be called so the text or whatever you are drawing in that object will be painted in the new position.

> Can I have an object that is drawn dynamically when created, have the
>   possibility to receive touch events

Yes, depending on what you want to achieve, you can override the method [onTouchEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) on your class that extends `View` or implement a [TouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnTouchListener%28android.view.View.OnTouchListener%29) to your object

Note: It is not advisable to draw that much view objects (100+) I remember some Google guys mentioning this, I'll edit this with the link as soon as I find it.

Comment: The touch-thing is not the hardest part at the moment, as I wrote - that works today. Is there any alternative to View I could use, which would solve the "move it around without it being repainted" issue and yet still have dynamic content?

Comment: That link would be interesting, if you can find it :)

Comment: my friend told me is in a video with Reto Meier however I can't find it, they are so many :S here is the link to their videos: http://www.youtube.com/user/GoogleDevelopers

Comment: Thanks. I'll see what I can find there. I've accepted your answer, although I would appreciate any alternatives if you can come up with any. Although I don't think the draw problem will be very big.

Answer (score 0):

After layout onDraw is pretty much a sure thing if a view moved -- though it's pretty hard to pinpoint in the Android source where this happens (props to anyone who does).
Believe me, I feel you - I posted https://plus.google.com/117549329232493334054/posts/FMf8RfhFceC because the same problem happens when using LayoutTransition.

Following the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#layers-anims) you may move the view by using view property animation (possibly ViewPropertyAnimator; I'm just learning this myself). You can listen to the end of that animation and then 'cement' the position of the view by running a layout. Also, we're supposed to trigger layout by putting a new LayoutParams on a view rather than calling `layout` directly.